# Light a led without GPIO board

Tags: pi-2, hardware, led

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the pi pins directly to toggle a led programmatically.

I don't have a GPIO board. Is it possible to connect the led to the pins and control it from the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, You can connect LEDs directly to Pi's pins. The Pi has many GPIOs on the header and you can use any one of them and connect an LED on a breadboard.

Here is one very well explained tutorial for the same:- [Click Here](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/27968772-turning-on-an-led-with-your-raspberry-pis-gpio-pins)

Here is reference image about LED Connection.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a breadboard. Let's assume I only have the Raspberry Pi accessible via wifi and an LED. Is it possible to turn on/off the LED this way?

Comment: Which Raspberry Pi model you have?
Without connecting LED how can you turn ON LED?

Comment: I have a Raspberry PI 2 B+. I don't have that kind of board with many holes in it, but I would like to use the pins from Raspberry Pi directly. Isn't that possible? How can I connect the LED to them?

Comment: That board helps you to avoid any false short circuit when connecting and if you really not want to use that one then get wires and connect same connection manually without board.

Comment: I have updated answer with LED Connection image you can connect something like that.

Comment: Yes, I think I have some wires around. :) Do I really need a resistor too? What is it for?

Comment: * Therefore putting the resistors in the circuit will ensure that only this small current will flow and the Pi will not be damaged.* – Actually looks like that's required. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes,
We have to limit the current passing thru circuit to avoid damage to LED/Pins. You can use any resistor in between 330 ohm to 1 kohm.
Let me know if you have any other doubt about hardware connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43444/discussion-between-hallmark-and-ionic-bizu).

Comment: Actually the resistor in an LED circuit isn't there so much to protect the Pi as it is to protect the LED, which will probably burn out before anything else (although I can't promise that isn't risky for the pi either).  Anyway, 330+ ohm's is probably massive overkill.  You can find "led resistor calculators" online to confirm this, but the formula is a version of Ohm's law: resistance = voltage / current.  The "voltage" in this case includes the forward drop of the LED, which might be -1.5 to -3 V; if we then assume 15 mA of current, that's (3.3 - 1.5) = 1.8 / 0.015 = 120 ohms.

Comment: ...It could even be as little as half that with some LEDs but 120 is a safe starting point.  You are also probably okay going with 20 mA current *but do beware not to exceed ~80-90 mA total from all the GPIOs* if you are connecting multiple LEDs to different pins. http://ledcalc.com/

Comment: Yes, 
At last I suggest to go with 1K.